# A more Functional implementation?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The below method simply parses a CSV file which is ID,DATE,NUMBER.

Is there an implementation of this that is more functional -- particularly something that didn't use a mutable collection, and returned an immutable collection? All of the code I have after this doesn't require mutability in the data structures.

I obviously don't want to make the code any more inefficient or ugly than it already is -- but I'd be keen to know if a more functional programming capable engineer would have done it differently?

```
def parseFile() : HashMap[String,ListBuffer[String]] = {

   val userDataSet = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String,ListBuffer[String]]

   for ( ln <- io.Source.stdin.getLines ) {

      val cols = ln.split(",")
      var values : ListBuffer[String] = userDataSet.getOrElse( cols(0), null )
      if ( values == null ) {
         values = ListBuffer.empty[String]
         userDataSet( cols( 0 ) ) = values
      }

      values += cols(2)
   }

   HashMap[String,ListBuffer[String]]() ++ userDataSet
}
```

Comment: Note that `ln split ','` is faster and less problematic than `ln split ","`.  When you use a String, it's taken as a regular expression and compiled.  I imagine some caching of the results is done, but even so it is far faster to split on a char than to look up a compiled regex.  And it's very easy to forget that it's a regex if later that comma later changes to, say, a period.  I always use `rx split line` for regex splits because it's faster and clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's fix up what you've got already:

```
def parseFile(): Map[String, ListBuffer[String]] = { // always use interfaces (Map, not HashMap)
  val userDataSet = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, ListBuffer[String]]
  for (ln <- io.Source.stdin.getLines) {
    val Array(id, date, number) = ln.split(",")  // pattern match with names for clarity
    val values = userDataSet.getOrElseUpdate(id, ListBuffer.empty)
    values += number
  }
  userDataSet.toMap
}
```

Note that even if `getOrElseUpdate` wasn't there, you'd still want to avoid the return-null-and-check thing by simply doing `!userDataSet.contains(id)`.  Alternatively, you could use `.get(id)`, which returns an `Option`.

Now for the functional solution.  When you want to build up a collection by traversing some other collection, you probably want a "fold":

```
def parseFile(): Map[String, Vector[String]] = {
  val lines = io.Source.stdin.getLines
  lines.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Vector[String]]) { (userDataSet, ln) =>
    val Array(id, date, number) = ln.split(",")  // pattern match with names for clarity
    val existingValues = userDataSet.getOrElse(id, Vector.empty)
    val updatedValues = existingValues :+ number
    userDataSet + (id -> updatedValues)         // update the Map with the new key/value
  }
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for being so thorough. I'll mark it correct, but a couple of questions. One, your functional version reads all lines into memory. Is there a less memory intensive way to do that and maintain the remaining logic? Second, it appears the code allocates a new instance for userDataSet every time through the loop -- does Scala optimize that in some reasonable way, do you know? Thanks.

Comment: 1) It doesn't read all lines into memory.  `getLines` returns an iterator, so `lines` is an iterator, and `foldLeft` traverses that iterator, just like `foreach` does in your version.  2) Yes, it allocates a new Map (and new Vector) on every iteration so that it uses only immutable data structures.  That's a reality of functional programming; it's safer and cleaner, but performance may vary.  You can sometimes optimize with parallelization (but that would mean reading all lines into memory up front).  And Scala's collections try to minimize copying for you.

Comment: Thanks again dhg, great answer, very clear and understandable.

Comment: Allocating a new map every time doesn't have a big impact on performance because scala uses very efficient data structures. Immutable hash maps are implemented as hash tries (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) that allow you to create modified copies very quickly by sharing most of the data between copies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be "super-functional" you can do it with scalaz-stream (https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream).

Full gist is here: https://gist.github.com/ezhulenev/9966059.

To understand runFoldMap you also need to take a look at Monoid concept: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monoid.html. (Map is monoid, Vector is monoid, Map of Vectors is monoid too)

```
val csv =
"""|0,2014-01-01,1
   |0,2014-01-02,2
   |1,2014-01-01,3
   |1,2014-01-01,4""".stripMargin

val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.getBytes)

val process = io.linesR(is).
  map(_.split(",")).               // split to columns
  map(arr => (arr(0), arr(2))).    // pick id & number columns
  runFoldMap { case (id, number) => Map(id -> Vector(number)) }

val output: Map[String, Vector[String]] = process.run
println(s"Output: ")
output.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(1,Vector(3, 4))
(0,Vector(1, 2))
```